# Typescript extension method compiling but not working at run time

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have extended the String prototype in Typescript with a simple method:

**StringExtensions.ts**

```
String.prototype.toCleanedTitleCase = function ():string {
    let titleCase = this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()
    })
    return titleCase.replace(new RegExp(" ", 'g'), "").replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'), "")
}
```

Then added an interface in a definition file:

**StringExtensions.d.ts**

```
interface String {
    toCleanedTitleCase():String;
}
```

Then calling it:

**index.ts**

```
console.log(("Some string that needs a-sorting").toCleanedTitleCase();
```

All compiles fine, but when I run my app (node js), I get "xxx.toCleanedTitleCase" is not a function.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: That was just an example, get the same error on normal strings

Comment: Have you inspected the compiled js to make sure the function is indeed there? My guess is that you are neither setup for AMD nor compiling to a single output file and therefore the StringExtensions content isn't making it into the output. It will still compile if you have a ///<reference> to the file.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Adding require("./StringExtensions) to the top of my index fixed it

Comment: Where did you put this require("./StringExtensions)? To the top of your index? Where is this? your index.ts? If I put a similar line like this in my index.ts, it does not even compile at compile time.

Comment: `
"paths": {
      "@extensions/*": [
        "src/extensions/*.extensions.ts"
      ]
    }
`

and `import '@extensions/array';` in file where extension method used works for me